# Vue computed issues with accessing API search results

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created an Anime Search App with Vue.js using the new script setup. I am fetching data from an API and I would like to display the number of search results displayed. Currently I am having trouble figuring out how to access those results. I have it displaying "50" for each result at the moment, but it is connected to the API's original data I believe. It is not connected to my search results for the title of each anime. I would like to display the number of titles shown. Can someone help me figure this out please? I am a beginner to Vue and JS in general. Thank you very much!

Code for my search page:

```
 <template>
    <header>
            <div class="img-scroll img">
      <h1>Anime Search</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
            <main class="animeSearch">
            <form class="search-box" @submit.prevent="HandleSearch">
                    <input 
                        type="search" 
                        class="search-field" 
                        placeholder="Search for an anime..."
                        required
                        v-model="search_query" />
                </form>
                <p>{{ resultCount }} results!</p>
                <Swiper :slides-per-view="4" :space-between="50" class="cards" v- 
      if="animelist.length > 0">
                <SwiperSlide class="card" v-for="anime in animelist" 
                        :key="anime.mal_id"
                        :anime="anime">
                    
            <a :href="anime.url" target="_blank">
                <img 
                    :src="anime.image_url" 
                    :alt="anime.title + ' Poster'" 
                />
                <h3>{{ anime.title }}</h3>
            </a>
        </SwiperSlide>
                </Swiper>
                <div class="no-results" v-else>
                    <h3>Type in an Anime and hit 'enter' for search results.<br>
                    Use your cursor to swipe through images.<br>
                    Click on the image for information about the anime.<br>
                    Happy searching!...</h3>
                </div>
            </main>
             <footer>
      <p>&copy Megan Louise 2022</p>
      </footer>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
    import { computed } from "vue";
    import "swiper/css";
    export default {
      components: {
        Swiper,
        SwiperSlide,
      },
        setup() {
            const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
            console.log(swiper);
            };
            const search_query = ref("");
            const animelist = ref([]);
            const HandleSearch = async () => {
                animelist.value = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime? 
      q=${search_query.value}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => data.results);
                search_query.value = "";
            };
            const onSlideChange = () => {
            console.log('slide change');
            };
            const resultCount = computed(() => {
                return animelist.value.length;
                console.log('resultCount');
        });
            return {
                search_query,
                animelist,
                HandleSearch,
                onSwiper,
                resultCount,
                onSlideChange
            };
        },
    }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    input[type='search'] {
    font-family: 'BIZ UDGothic', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid #FD8721;
    color: #FD8721;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    }
    h3 {
    color: #ECC013;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #FD8721;
    font-weight: 400;
    }
    .cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 10px 40px;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
    
    .card {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    img {
        cursor: grab;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        transition: 0.4s;
        border: 2px solid #BA1039;
    }
    img:hover {
            transform: scale(1.05);
        }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 820px) { 
    h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You have a computed value which returns the length of the array, which is the number of items returned.  Yet, there is also another property in the data called "last_page" with a value of 3. So it seems you will need to add pagination to display all the data and calculate the total.  And if that is what you are asking then we would need to know more about the API to understand how it handles pagination.

Comment: The array that is being accessed is not from my search results. That is my issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Jikan API documentation, v3 of the API is being deprecated starting from March 1st 2022 - https://docs.google.com/document/d/172RQ9wWiXqOnGqjXrV3cxMNceiqwCjxjprSFuyLwQJM/edit

You must migrate to v4 before September 1st 2022 when v3 will be gone. According to the [v4 documentation](https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#operation/getAnimeSearch) you should change your API request to be
https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=xxxx&page=yyy&limit=zzz
The response will contain information about the pagination - current page, number of items on the page, whether this is the last page and the total number of results:

```json
{
  "pagination":
  {
    "last_visible_page":1,
    "has_next_page":false,
    "current_page":1,
    "items":
    {
      "count":20,
      "total":20,
      "per_page":25
    }
  },
  data: [....]
}
```

And the `data` key will contain the items for the current page